# How to use npapi plugins in b2g firefox OS

Tags: firefox, npapi, firefox-os, b2g

This is my first time on this site. I have a HTML/CSS/JS application. For that application to work, we also have a browser npapi plugin ".so" file that is installed in plugins dir of firefox. This works on firefox browser on Linux. Now I want my application to run on Firefox OS (B2G). How do I port that ".so" plugin to firefox OS?.

What I have done is, I have built B2G and flashed it on my test device. I have built that plugin for android platform by using gecko sdk and firefox OS source. I have pushed my .so file in FFOS phone in /system/lib as well as /system/b2g (the folders where I can see other .so files.). Is that the correct approach? What else do I need to do to make it work. Currently my application is unable to load that plugin ( I checked using ./run-gdb ).

Any pointers would be helpful. I have gone through the documentation on mozilla website and also googled it alot but couldn't find the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: A bit more search revealed to me that NPAPI is not supported on firefox OS :((. My bad.
But I do see a lot of source and compiled files for npapi within firefox OS source code tree under 'gecko/dom/plugins/base/' and 'objdir-gecko/dom/plugins/base/'. What are these about?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, NPAPI is not supported on Firefox OS / B2G.
You do see code for it in the tree (and maybe even in the object directories) because much of the code is actually being used over different products (desktop Firefox, mobile Firefox, Firefox OS, ...).

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla use single gecko engine to support all platform browsers. Those plugins are only used by desktop browsers.

Comment: On Firefox for Android plugin code is used to support Flash as well.